# select rows with zero child elements (join)

Tags: sql, abap

I've got 2 tables. There is a constraint between these 2 tables.

`Table1 : Table2 = 1 : n`

I would like to select the keys of the `Table1` elements which GOT no entry in `Table2`.

Example:

```
|    Table 1         |
|Key |Col1 |Col2 |...|
|0001|.... |.... |...|
|0002|.... |.... |...|
|0003|.... |.... |...|
|0004|.... |.... |...|

|    Table 2         |
|Tab1|Col1 |Col2 |...|
|0001|.... |.... |...|
|0001|.... |.... |...|
|0003|.... |.... |...|
|0002|.... |.... |...|

Desired output:
0004
```

The output is the only entry of `table1` which got no child entry in `table2`.

I've tried many different options like:

```
SELECT 
    Key
    FROM Table1
    WHERE 
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 
            WHERE Table1~Key = Table2~Tab1 
            GROUP BY Table2~Tab1 )

SELECT COUNT(Table2)
    Key
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 
        ON Table1~Key = Table2~Tab1.

...
```

But none of them work.
Does anyone got a working query for **ABAP**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table1 where key not in (select tab1 from table2)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. just another little question, is there any negative performance impact?

Comment: well.. compared to what i guess.  if you get multiple working queries, then check the execution plans to see the differences

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
select key from table1 where not EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM table2
              WHERE table1.key=table2.tab1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
SELECT Key FROM Table1
WHERE key not in (SELECT distinct tab1 FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without subselect:

```
SELECT t1~Key FROM Table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2
WHERE t2~Key is null
```